# Vsphere client could not to connect to (IP of Vcenter).Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, clone

When I was connected to the vCenter server with the vSphere client and cloning a VM, my connection was broken.  I tried to reconnect to vCenter with the vSphere client and encoutered this message:

[image]

Comment: Either the server is down, your connection to the server no longer works, or you simply have to try two times. Does the web client still work?

Comment: Look at the log files (of both your vsphere client and on the vcenter server) for details on that error.

Comment: Could your cloned VM got the IP .17  ? please close the VM and try again.

Comment: Connect to each host directly and define whether the vCenter is up and running. If yes, log in to it and double check logs. Try to reboot vCenter.